# How sort xml by distinct data using classic asp?

Tags: xml, xpath, asp-classic, vbscript

this is my xml

```
<XMLResponse>
<Product>
<Items>
<ID>AA</ID>
</Items>
<Items>
<ID>BB</ID>
</Items>
<Items>
<ID>CC</ID>
</Items>
<Items>
<ID>AA</ID>
</Items>
<Items>
<ID>AA</ID>
</Items>
<Items>
<ID>BB</ID>
</Items>
</Product>
</XMLResponse>
```

this is the code i using in my classic asp

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"  

Dim xd3   
Set xd3 = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")   
xd3.async = False  
xd3.load(Server.MapPath("01.xml"))
For Each item In xd3.selectNodes("/XMLResponse/Product/Items[not(/ID=preceding-sibling:Product/Items/ID)]/ID")
response.write item.getElementsByTagName("items").item(0).getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0).text
next
%>
```

But the about asp code is not working fine

I need output like this with distinct ID's

ID: AA
ID: BB
ID: CC

Answer (score 1):

ive found its hard to get the path of the select nodes just right... you may use an xml explorer that outputs the path (nice xml explorer xmlexplorer.codeplex.com/) then other thing you may consider is traversing the tree with

```
    Set entitys = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("items")
for i = 0 to entitys.length - 1
%><%=entitys(i).text%><%=entitys(i).getAttribute("source")%>
<%
next
```

that will pull the text of the node or any attributes (looks like you dont have any yet)

also looks at the MSDN XML DOM msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757828(VS.85).aspx  to see how to get first child or enumerate children

i dont know if its bad to ask but im just starting and need points so i can add links :) hope i helped...